# Synchronize virtual machines through the internet

Tags: windows, debian, virtualization, synchronization

I have a windows host machine serving a Debian guest on VMWare. I have set up my working enviroment in the VM and I am including some shared folders to the VM. Is it possible to set up exactly the same VM image on my notebook and my webserver and synchronize them through the internet, including the data in the shared folders?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of synchronizing the VM file itslef, which would be more then a GB, you can :

Shutdown your existing VM
Export your VM via VMware
Install Vmware onto your other machines
Import your Vm onto the other machines

You can then use `rsync` in a script to setup sync jobs (Syncing Data Only) across all 3 machines. You can also make use of Dropbox on all of your 3 machines to move files in between your desktops / laptops.

Hope that Helps